# Android - Speech Recognition - No recognition result matched

Tags: android, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I am trying to implement `speech recognition`. I keep getting the error:

```
ERROR_NO_MATCH - No recognition result matched - 7
```

I can't find anything that explain what does this means.
What does `"No recognition result matched"` mean?

Answer (score 0):

you need to enable partial results first, and to call UNSTABLE_TEXT

```
// When creating the intent, set the partial flag to true
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PARTIAL_RESULTS,true);
```

use the partialResults returned in onPartialResults(). In the returned bundle "SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION" has all the terms minus the last term and "android.speech.extra.UNSTABLE_TEXT" has the last missing recognized term.

```
@Override
public void onPartialResults(Bundle partialResults) {
    ArrayList<String> data = 
    partialResults.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
    ArrayList<String> unstableData = 
    partialResults.getStringArrayList("android.speech.extra.UNSTABLE_TEXT");
    mResult = data.get(0) + unstableData.get(0);
}
```

you can follow below link for better understanding -

[speech recognition](https://github.com/nenick/android-app-quacc/blob/master/app/src/main/java/de/nenick/quacc/speechrecognition/speech/RecognizerListenerWithOfflineWorkaround.java)

Answer (score -1):

No recognition result matched. Meaning superbox s3 cannot us voice command message no recognition result matched . Come up on screen

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).